# Can't login via Facebook. Blank screen after giving permission

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, fbsdk

I'm attempting a Facebook login through Parse. When I grant the app permission, the popup web view goes blank and hangs. I have the option to hit "Done" and close the web view, but it doesn't log in. What am I doing wrong?

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import ParseFacebookUtilsV4    

PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(["public_profile","email"]) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                print("User logged in through Facebook!")
            }
        } else {
            print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    }
```

I get no error messages whatsoever. It just hangs on a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this by adding this line right before the call to login.

```
[[PFFacebookUtils facebookLoginManager] setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb];
```